# Связь один-к-одному и нормализация базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных

Предматная область такова: есть пользователи и талоны к врачу, которые они могу брать (заказывать). Связь между ними - один-ко-многим. Заказ должен быть подтвержден пользователем каким-то способом. Талон в каждый момент времени может иметь один статус - "свободен", "заказан, но не подтвержден юзером", "заказан и подтвержден юзером".

На данный ммеется две таблицы: Пользователи (**Users**) и билеты (**Ticket**):

[image]

Но поля, помеченные зеленым в таблице **Ticket** (`Status`, `UserId`, `VerificationCode` и `OrderDate`) не имеют непосредственного отношения к талону - это атрибуты заказа. Все они, кроме статуса, содержат пустые значения (`NULL`), если талон еще не занят.

Вопрос такой: хорошая ли сейчас структура данных, либо она все-таки ошибочна и в этой ситуации требуется другая? Тажке интересно узнать какой из нормальных форм соответствует текущая структура; имеются ли в ней нарушения нормальных форм и если да, то каким способом их исправить.

Была идея вынести упомянутые атрибуты в отдельную таблицу (например 'Заказы') и связать её с талонами (таблицей **Ticket**) один-к-одному. Но в этом случае я получаю лишнюю сложность при работе с талонами и заказами из приложения. Буду рад услышать любые советы, спасибо.

Comment: а какой практический смысл в пустом талоне (свободен, который)?

Comment: Смысл в том, что юзеры видят свободные дату и время и могут взять этот талон.

Comment: то есть вы генерите тикеты на определенный срок? скажем на неделю вперед, да? вот этот момент как раз и видится неоптимальным. т.е. вы храните пустоту. в случае изменения расписания вам придется совершать дополнительные действия. например, врач заболел, или другой форсмажор. вам придется кучу (или сколько их там будет) тикетов как-то переобрабатывать. кроме того, не знаю вашего случая, но бывает, что заранее нельзя сказать сколько будет тикетов, скажем, за день, т.к. может быть разное время обслуживания в зависимости от конкретных пациентов. имхо.

Comment: Да, тикеты генерятся на несколько дней вперед. В случае изменений есть функционал, удаляющий/изменяющий тикеты. Я понимаю, что заранее сказать ничего нельзя, но ведь регистратуры всех больниц/клиник именно так и работают.

Comment: @Shad регистратуры печатают талончики на каждый день ? А я думал у них там календарь такой и они галочки ставят на занятое время приема (типа таблица - специалист, и его неделя - так по моему примерно выглядит журнал в регистратуре) в компе этого не нужно, т.к. ничего не мешает привязать доктора к пациенту в связывающей таблице "сеансы" в которой "дата, доктор, пациент, (иногда продолжительность)"

Comment: да нет же, не печатают. Здесь вопрос именно в расписании, вы сами сказали, что они ставят галочки на время приема, но ведь это самое время приема нужно знать. Это и есть "пустой талон" в моем случае.

Comment: > но ведь регистратуры всех больниц/клиник именно так и работают.

у меня есть противоположные наблюдения.  
в случае живой очереди талоны печатаются по запросу непосредственно в день обращения, там время не важно, есть часы работы врача. так работают, например, врачи в нашей п-ке.  
в случае приема по записи, запись ведет регистратор совместно с врачом. есть дни приема, а время приема согласовывается с врачом - зависит от продолжительности предполагаемого времени обслуживания (15 минут/1,5 часа), естественно у пациента интересуются удобным для него временем. так у зубных врачей...

Comment: Вам повезло :) Но у меня не случай живой очереди, а онлайн-регистрация. И есть требование в фиксированном расписании.

Comment: ну это все ведет к простою врачей или наоборот лишнему времени ожидания. если, например, на пациента по часу, то 8 пациентов в день? охота за талонами, перекупщики, мафия... =)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы говорить о нормализации, нужно определить естественные ключи и зависимости. А у вас видны только ID.

Имеет ли смысл неоприходованный талон? Учет бумаги?

Что касается "лишней сложности при работе с талонами и заказами из приложения", то можно создать представления, восстанавливающее представленную схему.

Comment: Естественный ключ талона - это дата, время и врач. Эта тройка атрибутов уникально идентифицурет талон. За совет с представлением, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

что мне не нравится в вашей структуре:
1) `users.clinicId` - клиника к пользователю никакого отношения не имееют, юзеры посещают клинику и покупают в ней тикеты. свяующее звено между юзером и клиникой это тикет. если же структура делается для одной клиники то это поле вообще лишнее
2) `tickets.date, tickets.time` - здесь нехватает поля duration, длительности приема при его добавлении у вас автоматически появляется возможность прогнозировать занятость опр. доктора и как результат не надо будет генерировать тикеты наперед. поле должно иметь стартное значение для каждого типа доктора (видимо это означает что должны быть таблицы doctors и doctorTypes)
3) `tickets.<green marked fields>` - все они должны быть вынесены в отдельную таблицу которая называется user_tickets.
4) `users.lastActivityDate` - не совсем понятно зачем вам мониторить активность юзера, обычно в таких случаях создают записи в хистори таблице. это логичнее чем обновлять таблицу с информацией о юзерах в которой информация которая будет менятся очень редко

примерно такое у вас получится в результате:

```
users:        id, extClientType, lastActivityDate, authId, details, type
userTickets:  userId, ticketId, status, verificationCode, orderDate
tickets:      ticketId, clinicId, doctorId, date, time, duration, details
```

Comment: 2) Интересное предложение, спасибо. Пункты 1) и 4) - солгасен: это лишняя инфа, но вопрос не в них. 3) А почему "должны"?

Comment: потому что они не относятся непосредственно ни к тикету ни к юзеру. только к их связи